# Jackson - Serialize Map with Object as key to array

Tags: jackson, quarkus, jsonb, jackson-databind, quarkus-rest-client

I am migrating my Quarkus app from using Json-B to Jackson. Now I have difference with how Jackson and Json-B serialize Map where key is some Java Object.

Example of the transfer object:

```
public class Car {
  private Integer id;
  private String color;

  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getColor() {
    return color;
  }

  public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
  }
}
```

My resource example:

```
@GET
@Path("/test")
public Map<Car, String> test() {
  Car car = new Car();
  car.setId(1);
  car.setColor("Red");
    
  Map<Car, String> map = new HashMap<>();
  map.put(car, "First");
  return map;
}
```

With Jackson result of serialization is (only use toString() for serializating Car object:

```
{
    "com.example.app.dto.Car@42773f1c": "First"
}
```

With Json-B result of serialization is:

```
[
    {
        "key": {
            "color": "Red",
            "id": 1
        },
        "value": "First"
    }
]
```

Is there any Jackson configuration that can achieve to have the same result with Jackson as Json-B provides, with maps having key as object?
I can achieve it for this specific case with custom serializer, but I need a general solution.

Comment: have you tried override toString() in Car class?

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom jackson serializer for your `Car` object and register it with a `io.quarkus.jackson.ObjectMapperCustomizer`.
You can find all information in [official guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-json)

Comment: I am looking for a general solution, not having custom serializer for each object having as key in some Map. As sad I did switch of the libraries in existing, big, project. So would be helpfull if some general handler works